# Lua (Filter Forge) - Trouble implementing roll on a sphere with working yaw and pitch

Tags: lua

I am trying to expand on something I had working using just yaw and pitch (rotation and tilt) controls for a mapped sphere. I added a roll component which works for just moving the sphere, but not for keeping the gradients used (via hsl conversion) coordinated with the movements.

Looking for answers online goes straight into math (still struggling with trig) I can't follow well enough to apply to this case. Code gets hashed when inserted. Here is the link to a trimmed down version of the script:

[3d sphere v.0.0.1](https://github.com/eyeofparadox/ff_lua_scripts/blob/main/3d%20sphere%20v.0.0.1.lua)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly do not submit questions with the intent to answer them myself. I just keep hammering at a problem until a solution presents itself. Often answers come via the Filter Forge forums, sometimes through online searches (and often other stack overflow questions I did not find before submitting my own), and more often recently through simple trial and error.

So, yes, I came up with a solution. I was right that the order of operations was the key. There are probably other, better solutions out there, so please share if you have one. It could help whoever finds their way here.

You can see my answer [here](https://github.com/eyeofparadox/ff_lua_scripts/blob/main/3d%20sphere%20v.0.0.3.lua).